# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' python

Tags: python-3.x

def withdraw_fxn(withdraw,acct_deposit):
cur.execute("SELECT acct_deposit FROM atm WHERE acct_name = ?",       (acct_deposit,))
act_deposit = cur.fetchone()

```
acct_deposit = int(act_deposit)

if withdraw > acct_deposit:
    list1.insert(END, ("your balance is low "))

elif acct_deposit > withdraw:
    acct_deposit =  acct_deposit - withdraw
```

it throws the type error

Comment: Please post the code you are asking about.

Comment: Hello could you please upvote my question so I can post an image, I need to have +10 reputation to post an image :(

Comment: Post the code as text, not an image.